# Splitting a dictionary by key suffixes

Tags: python

I have a dictionary like so

```
d = {"key_a":1, "anotherkey_a":2, "key_b":3, "anotherkey_b":4}
```

So the values and key names are not important here. The key (no pun intended) thing, is that related keys share the same *suffix* in my example above that is `_a` and `_b`.

These suffixes are **not** known before hand (they are not always `_a` and `_b` for example, and there are an unknown number of different suffixes.

What I would like to do, is to extract out related keys into their own dictionaries, and have all generated dictionaries in a list.
The output from above would be

`output = [{"key_a":1, "anotherkey_a":2},{"key_b":3, "anotherkey_b":4}]`

My current approach is to first get all the suffixes, and then generate the sub-dicts one at a time and append to the new list

```
output = list()
# Generate a set of suffixes
suffixes = set([k.split("_")[-1] for k in d.keys()])

# Create the subdict and append to output
for suffix in suffixes:
    output.append({k:v for k,v in d.items() if k.endswith(suffix)})
```

This **works** (and is not prohibitively slow or anyhting) but I am simply wondering if there is a more elegant way to do it with a list or dict comprehension? Just out of interest...

Comment: Correctioin: `output.append({k:v for k,v in d.items() if k.endswith(suffix)})` according to your expected output format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your output a defaultdict rather than a list, with suffixes as keys:

```
from collections import defaultdict
output = defaultdict(lambda: {})
for k, v in d.items():
    prefix, suffix = k.rsplit('_', 1)
    output[suffix][k] = v
```

This will split your dict in a single pass and result in something like:

> output = {"a" : {"key_a":1, "anotherkey_a":2}, "b": {"key_b":3, "anotherkey_b":4}}

and if you insist on converting it to a list, you can simply use:

```
output = list(output.values())
```

Comment: After your suggestion I actually used a `dict` as my output rather than a list, as it was in fact more useful!

Answer (score 1):

You could condense the lines

```py
output = list()

for suffix in suffixes:
    output.append({k:v for k,v in d.items() if k.endswith(suffix)})
```

to a list comprehension, like this

```py
[{k:v for k,v in d.items() if k.endswith(suffix)} for suffix in suffixes]
```

Whether it is more elegant is probably in the eyes of the beholder.

The approach suggested by @Błotosmętek will probably be faster though, given a large dictionary, since it results in less looping.

Comment: Thanks the ..`for suffix in suffixes` addition i was trying to figure out and was confusing myself!

Answer (score 0):

```
def sub_dictionary_by_suffix(dictionary, suffix):
    sub_dictionary = {k: v for k, v in dictionary.items() if k.endswith(suffix)}

    return sub_dictionary
```

I hope it helps